# WPF locks images when referenced through a resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

When I load in a resource dictionary, it loads all elements into the canvas fine and shows all of them properly. The problem occurs when I want to delete an element. If I delete the element, I also want to delete the image associated with that element. But the problem is windows won't let me delete it because it was referenced by the resource dictionary.

This is the code I use to load the file:

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary();
dict.Source = new Uri(xamlFilePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);

this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);

this.UpdateLayout();
```

The lockout occurs when dict.Source is called.

The images are stored in a folder near the XAML file. In the XAML file this is what is stored:

```
<Style x:Key="objectPhoto" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="116" />
    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="654" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF000000" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="347" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="347" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Image">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Card Design Images\objectPhoto.png" />
            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Which image? There isn't any in the code you've posted.

Comment: Hello. Maybe you should consider using other thing than a ResourceDictionary. If you want to load and delete things, a database or something like that would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Bob I'm thinking it would be better to do something like that, or seeing as though I already have export functionality that outputs a XAML, I could just loop through all elements in the file and style them that way,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is not the ResourceDictionary, but the BitmapFrame that is implicitly created from the Value string in the Setter for the Source property. Unless you do not explicitly specify a BitmapCacheOption, WPF keeps its source file open.

You may create the Setter's Value like this, and set `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`:

```
<Style TargetType="Image">
    <Setter Property="Source">
        <Setter.Value>
            <BitmapImage CacheOption="OnLoad"
                         UriSource="Card Design Images\objectPhoto.png"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```